# Create a new column which name was from a field of a table

Tags: r, bioinformatics

For example, I have a table as following:(let's call it a)

```
SNP         ID    ALLE1    ALLE2
SNPNAME1    1      A        A
SNPNAME2    1      A        G
SNPNAME3    1      G        G
...
```

I want to write a function to create a new table from above:

```
ID SNPNAME1  SNPNAME2  SNPNAME3...
1    AA        AG         GG
...
```

So my idea was to create a NULL object b first, then I add a new column "ID" to it which I can do as following:

```
b$ID=NA
```

Then I try to add a new column which name is from `a[1,]$SNP`, I tried to this by using the following statement:

```
b$a[1,]$SNP=NA
```

However I can't. 
Then I tried to use

```
b$get(a[1,]$SNP)=NA
```

or

```
c=quote(a[1,]$SNP)
b$eval(c)=NA
```

But all above didn't now work.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to build an object yourself. First let's make some example data that I think is representative for your situation:

```
df = data.frame(name = paste('spam', rep(1:10, 5), sep = ''), 
                ID = rep(1:5, each = 10),
                var1 = sample(c('A', 'G'), 50, replace = TRUE),
                var2 = sample(c('A', 'G'), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

amd combine the var columns:

```
df = transform(df, comb_var = paste(var1, var2, sep = ''))
head(df)
   name ID var1 var2 comb_var
1 spam1  1    A    G       AG
2 spam2  1    G    G       GG
3 spam3  1    G    G       GG
4 spam4  1    A    G       AG
5 spam5  1    A    G       AG
6 spam6  1    G    A       GA
```

And then use `dcast` to perform the transformation:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID ~ name, value.var = 'comb_var')
  ID spam1 spam10 spam2 spam3 spam4 spam5 spam6 spam7 spam8 spam9
1  1    AG     GA    GG    GG    AG    AG    GA    GG    GA    GG
2  2    AA     GA    AG    GA    GA    AG    AG    AA    GG    AG
3  3    GG     AG    AG    AG    GA    GG    GA    GA    AA    AG
4  4    AA     AA    GA    GA    GA    GA    AA    GA    AG    AA
5  5    AG     AA    GA    AA    GG    GG    GG    GA    GG    GG
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a)
DT[, setNames(as.list(paste0(ALLE1, ALLE2)), SNP), by = ID]

##    ID SNPNAME1 SNPNAME2 SNPNAME3
## 1:  1       AA       AG       GG
```

Using Paul's data

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, structure(as.list(paste0(var1, var2)), names = as.character(name)), by = ID]

##    ID spam1 spam2 spam3 spam4 spam5 spam6 spam7 spam8 spam9 spam10
## 1:  1    AA    AA    GA    GG    AG    GA    GA    AG    GG     AA
## 2:  2    AA    AA    GA    GA    GA    AA    AG    GG    GG     GG
## 3:  3    AG    AG    AG    GA    AA    AG    GG    GA    AG     AA
## 4:  4    GA    GG    GA    AA    AG    GG    AA    AA    GG     AG
## 5:  5    AG    GA    GG    AG    AA    AG    AA    AA    GG     GA
```

Comment: I didn't find that the names were properly constructed so perhaps you would consider this minor modification: `DT[, setNames( as.list(paste0(ALLE1, ALLE2)), SNP), by = ID]` . Maybe there were changes in how `data.table` handles lists in the intervening 4 years, but I would have thought that `names=SNP` should have been `.Names=SNP`, but even that fails on my machine.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks. Must have been some change with `data.table`. Next time just edit it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- read.table(text="SNP         ID    ALLE1    ALLE2
SNPNAME1    1      A        A
SNPNAME2    1      A        G
SNPNAME3    1      G        G", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)

DFm <- melt(DF, id=c("SNP", "ID"))
dcast(DFm, ID~SNP, value.var="value", fun.aggregate=paste, collapse="")
#  ID SNPNAME1 SNPNAME2 SNPNAME3
#1  1       AA       AG       GG
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a `reshape2` answer I always try to see if there is a fairly straightforward base R solution. In this case (using Pauls's data) using `tapply()` with `I()` seems to rearrange the strings in a tabular arrangement (if you first prevent `transform from making a factor):

```
 df = transform(df, comb_var = paste(var1, var2, sep = ''),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 with(df, tapply(comb_var, list(ID, name), I))
#--------------------
  spam1 spam10 spam2 spam3 spam4 spam5 spam6 spam7 spam8 spam9
1 "AA"  "GA"   "GG"  "GG"  "GA"  "AG"  "AA"  "GG"  "GG"  "AG" 
2 "AA"  "AG"   "AA"  "AA"  "AA"  "GG"  "GG"  "AA"  "AA"  "GG" 
3 "GA"  "GA"   "GA"  "AG"  "AA"  "AG"  "GA"  "GG"  "AG"  "AG" 
4 "GG"  "AA"   "GG"  "GG"  "AA"  "GA"  "GA"  "GG"  "AA"  "AA" 
5 "AG"  "GA"   "AG"  "GG"  "GA"  "GA"  "AG"  "AA"  "GG"  "GG"
```